# Authentication line of python 2 code to py3

Tags: python

This is for seomoz API, here is code for python 2 that works:

```
return base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.secret_key, toSign, hashlib.sha1).digest())
```

I tried changing it to something like this to make it work with py3.5.1:

```
return (base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytearray(self.secret_key, "utf-8"),
bytearray(toSign,"utf-8"), hashlib.sha1).digest())).decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
```

But keep getting "authentication failed" error response from moz. [If it helps, here is full file.](https://github.com/seomoz/SEOmozAPISamples/blob/master/python/lsapi.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both functions for python 2.7 and 3.5 with:
secret_key = "sss"
toSign="toSign"

And the result was:
'7Zs94MRQfyNmonJhtgKT0QmHAcQ=' and '7Zs94MRQfyNmonJhtgKT0QmHAcQ='

So maybe any issue in toSign  = '%s\n%i' % (self.access_id, expires) ?

```
def signature(self, expires):
    toSign  = '%s\n%i' % (self.access_id, expires)
    return base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.secret_key, toSign, hashlib.sha1).digest())
```